Narrowing the return value of a function based on a flag nested in an option object passed as argument
I have a function that returns either an object or an array based on a flag nested in an option object:
type Option = {
  param: string
  raw?: boolean
  otherParam?: string;
}

type RawResponse = {
  message: string
  data: string[]
}

function fakeFetch() {
  return Promise.resolve({ message: "Hello", data: ["test1", "test2"] } as RawResponse)
}

async function foo(options: Option) {
  const response = await fakeFetch()

  if (options.raw) {
    return response
  }

  return response.data
}

However, if I use it and set the flag to false, it doesn't infer the right type (string[]) and then I cannot do .map() because RawResponse is not an array and then does not have the map property.
foo({param: "test", raw: false}).then(results => {
  results.map(result => console.log(result))
});

Is there a way to make TypeScript understand the right return type depending on the boolean value of the flag? I did try some things with generics but they didn't work.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads?

The current implementation does not leverage TypeScript's ability to infer return types based on the input flags. While the function foo aims to return either myObject or myResponse[], TypeScript does not inherently understand that the return type depends on the flag value. By defining the return type as a union (myObject | myResponse[]), TypeScript cannot determine which type is returned based on the flag at the call site. This leads to the error when attempting to call .map() on the results, as TypeScript considers the possibility of myObject being returned, which does not have a map method.

So, your possible approaches are overloads or a generic function returning a conditional type; both are shown in this playground link. Neither one is type checked very well inside the implementation; currently overloads are too loosely checked and generic conditionals are too strongly checked. Anyway, does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Yes it does, thanks.

If you want a function's return type to depend on its parameter types, you either have to overload the function, or make it generic.

Overloading the function involves declaring multiple call signatures, one for each supported way to call the function, and then implementing the function separately:
// call signatures
async function foo(options: Option & { raw: true }): Promise<RawResponse>;
async function foo(options: Option & { raw?: false }): Promise<string[]>;
async function foo(options: Option): Promise<RawResponse | string[]>;

// implementation
async function foo(options: Option) {
    const response = await fakeFetch()
    if (options.raw) {
        return response
    }
    return response.data
}


foo({ param: "test", raw: false }).then(results => {
    results.map(result => console.log(result)) // okay
});

I've given three call signatures: one where raw is true, one where it is missing or false, and the third where it is unspecified.  The third one is sort of a combination of the first two, so you might want to leave it out. But if you do leave it out, you can't call
declare const opt: Option;
foo(opt);

because the only supported call signatures are where you know whether or not raw is true.
The implementation is the same as your current one. Note that TypeScript doesn't actually check that the implementation satisfies each call signature separately.  If, for example, you change the options.raw check to the opposite !options.raw, the function will still compile, even though now the actual return types of the first two call signatures will be flipped.  It's just not within TypeScript's abilities to check each call signature that way; see microsoft/TypeScript#13235.

Making the function generic requires, in this case, that the return type be a conditional type:
async function foo<B extends boolean | undefined = undefined>(
    options: Option & { raw?: B }
): Promise<B extends true ? RawResponse : string[]> {
    const response = await fakeFetch()
    if (options.raw) {
        return response as any
    }
    return response.data as any
}

foo({ param: "test", raw: false }).then(results => {
    results.map(result => console.log(result)) // okay
});

Now the type of the options parameter is generic in the type B of the raw property, which is constrained to boolean | undefined, and which defaults to undefined. When you call foo(opt), TypeScript will infer B from the opt argument. If raw is true then B will be true. Likewise, if raw is false, then B will be false. If raw is missing, then inference will fail, and TypeScript will select the default of undefined. And if raw is only known to be boolean, then B will be boolean.
The return type of foo() depends on B, and is a Promise of the distributive conditional type B extends true ? RawResponse : string[].  If B is true then the return type is Promise<RawResponse>. If B is false or undefined then the return type is Promise<string[]>. And if B is a union type like boolean (which is shorthand for true | false) then the return type is Promise of the corresponding union of outputs.  So then when B is boolean, the return type is Promise<RawResponse | string[]>.
The implementation is the same as your original version at runtime, but you might notice I added type assertions to the any type in the return statements. That's because TypeScript is not currently able to verify that rseponse or response.data is of type Promise<B extends true ? RawResponse : string[]>, even after checking options.raw. There is  feature request at microsoft/TypeScript#33912 to improve that, and there's a pull request at microsoft/TypeScript#56941 which might actually make it into TypeScript 5.7 or 5.8, and at that point there might be a way to write such a function without type assertions or other loosening of type checking. But for now, we just need to deal with the fact that the implementation is not verified for correctness.

There you go, overloads or generics. Either way lets callers call the function and get different return types, neither way accurately type checks the implementation. I usually prefer generics to overloads, mostly because generics are more flexible, but it really depends on your use cases. Both versions work for the given example code.
Playground link to code

Just use a conditional type for the return type:
Playground
type Option = {
  flag: boolean
  otherParam: string;
}

type myObject = { myObject: true}
type myResponse = { myResponse: true}

declare function foo<O extends Option>(options: O): Promise<O extends {flag : true} ? myObject : myResponse[]>;

foo({flag: true, otherParam: 'boom'}).then(result => {
  result; // myObject
});




This doesn't work as written, try your call with flag: true
